# How to install Typescript 2.2 in Visual Studio 2017 v15.4.3

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I tried this hack: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14529 but got other terrible errors so I don't think it worked.

And 2.2 is not available under options here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55258

"Install-Package Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild -Version 2.2.2" did not work either, made the 2.2 show up on the dropdown but only as unavailable. https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild/2.2.2

[image: unavailable]

Comment: just a suggestion, if you can use [visual studio code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) for typescript project unless you have a specific dependency on VS. It comes pre-installed with typescript and has great tooling to upgrade / downgrade it's version.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, The perforce integration wasn't up to snuff for the other members of the team unfortunately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Run the visual studio installer and modify your visual studio install.  Under individual components you will see the versions of typescript available for install.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I am using VS 2019 and @ken-tucker answer did not worked for me. The Typescript version that I needed (3.6.2) did not appeared in the "Individual components" Tab.

I needed to install from [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TypeScriptTeam.TypeScript-362) and restart Visual Studio.